# undefined method `Calendar' for 2:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to put a calendar on my user page. I added route to `routes.rb` file. But I can not understand why it doesn't work.

**route.rb**

```
resources :users do
    resources :calendars
end
```

The error is said to be at line `21` of **calendars_controler.rb**:

```
   19   def new
   20     @user = current_user.id
   21     @calendar = @user.Calendar.new
   22   end
```

**application.erb**

```
<h1> <% picture3 = image_tag("../images/twit.png", :border =>0, :class =>"smallh1", :class => "blue")%> </h1>
<%= link_to picture3, new_user_calendar_path(current_user.id) %>
```

**models/user.rb**

```
 has_one :calendar 
    attr_accessible :calendar_id
```

I added the `user_id` field to the calendar *index* page.

**models/calendar.rb**

```
attr_accessible :event, :published_on, :description, :user_id
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

1. your `@user` variable is set to user's **ID**, not user model instance
2. you try to get the `Calendar` from `@user`, whilst `calendar` is the correct field name, defined at **models/user.rb**
3. you try to get the `calendar` from the **user id**, not from the **user**

**The solution is:**

1. replace line

   ```
   @user = current_user.id
   ```

   with

   ```
   @user = current_user
   ```
2. replace line

   ```
   @calendar = @user.Calendar.new
   ```

   with

   ```
   @calendar = @user.calendar.new
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `21` of your `calendars_controller.rb`

```
@calendar = @user.Calendar.new
```

with

```
@calendar = @user.calendar.new
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def new
    @user = current_user.id
    @calendar = @user.Calendar.new
    end
```

Here you are assigning `@user` instant variable to Fixnum (user id), and that doesn't make sense.

```
@user = current_user
```

This is correct variant. And yes, capital letters in Ruby are for Class names and Module names (which are some kind of special classes)

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved my problem thanks to you guy

for resolve i made that

def new
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.build_calendar
  end

when i use the association the function new do no exist it's build now

thanks again